# Why am i getting a column doesnt exist error with the name of the table

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio

Hi guys Im trying to retrieve some data I inserted into a database in a previous activity. This is my code to Retrieve the data

```
public class Display_data extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> Displist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView no_name;
    String db_Name;
    TextView namer;
    TextView Starter;
    TextView Ender;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            no_name = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Disp_list);
            String message = bundle.getString("package");
            String parameter;
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(message, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
            Cursor header;
            namer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.T1);
            try {
                header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no="+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3)), null);
                header.moveToFirst();
                String temp = header.getString((header.getColumnIndex("Train_name")));
                Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "blahhh:"+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Sucess!","temp:"+temp);
                Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Gotcha:"+temp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                namer.setText("Train Name: " + temp);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Final Error",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        db_Name=message.substring(0,(message.length()-3));
        try{
            Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select Stops From "+db_Name, null);
            while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
                String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Stops"));
                if(Displist.contains(name)) {

                }
                else {
                    Displist.add(name);
                    //Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Added :"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
            data_fetch.close();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Yeah"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Damn Why",e.toString());

        }
        try {

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Displist);
            no_name.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Display data error ",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

It has come to my notice that the section

```
try {
            header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no="+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3)), null);
            header.moveToFirst();
            String temp = header.getString((header.getColumnIndex("Train_name")));
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "blahhh:"+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Sucess!","temp:"+temp);
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Gotcha:"+temp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            namer.setText("Train Name: " + temp);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Final Error",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Returns the error

```
D/Final Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aa1000 (code 1): , while compiling: Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no=aa1000
```

I really don't understand this error as 'aa1000' was inserted into the database.

This is the definition for the database  'train_list'

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list ("
                + "Train_name VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_no VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_start VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_end VARCHAR,"
                + "Seats_Available VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO Train_list (Train_name, Train_no, Train_start, Train_end, Seats_Available) VALUES('"+str_Train_name + "',' " +str_Train_no + "', '" +str_Train_start+"','" +str_Train_end+"',' " +str_Train_seats +"');";
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "train no:"+str_Train_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Sorry Not Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error experienced",e.toString());
        }
```

I Checked the Android Monitor page and i did not find an error to suggest that "aa1000" had not been inserted into the database.

Please Do note that When inserting only `Train_name` and `Train_no` Were filled in the rest were left as null.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Learn to use parameters for your queries.  Don't munge query strings with user input!  Among other things, it will fix what seem like arcane syntax errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i was just following a tutorial Thats how they did it

Comment: . . Get a better tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `aa1000` into single quotes (**'aa1000'**):

Your `SQL` query should look like:

```
Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no='aa1000'
```

So modify your select string inside `db.rawQuery`:

```
"Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+"'";
```

However it is not advised to use `rawQuery` for select queries and passing parameters this way, better learn use the [`query`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

Comment: well that fixed the error now i have a new one but thanks mate !

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method declaration then implement as below :

```
Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)

rawQuery("SELECT Train_name FROM Train_list WHERE Train_no = ?", new String[] {message.substring(0,(message.length()-3)});
```

**Note** : ' ? ' replace selectionArgs actual value when query run into database