# Android Studio says database is empty when infact it is not

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio, indexoutofboundsexception

This Is the Code to insert items into my database called `Train_List`\

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list ("
                + "Train_name VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_no VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_start VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_end VARCHAR,"
                + "Seats_Available VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO Train_list (Train_name, Train_no, Train_start, Train_end, Seats_Available) VALUES('"+str_Train_name + "',' " +str_Train_no + "', '" +str_Train_start+"','" +str_Train_end+"',' " +str_Train_seats +"');";
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "train no:"+str_Train_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Sorry Not Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error experienced",e.toString());
        }
```

And I have observed that no `exceptions` were thrown and no entries are made in the logcat. Thus Leading me to believe that the data was successfully
inserted.

This is the code to Retrieve the data that was inserted:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        no_name = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Disp_list);
        String message = bundle.getString("package");
        String parameter;
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(message, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor header;
        namer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.T1);
        try {
            header = db1.rawQuery("Select * From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'", null);
            String temp = header.getString((header.getColumnIndex("Train_name")));
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "blahhh:"+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Sucess!","temp:"+temp);
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Gotcha:"+temp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            namer.setText("Train Name: " + temp);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Final Error",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This Throws the exception

```
D/Final Error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

From a little bit of googling i Know that this error is thrown when `null` is returned  into a cursor i do not understand why this is happening any hellp would be appreciated!

Comment: if you run query ""Select * From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'"" on a database does it return any rows?

Comment: you should always check if cursor is ! empty before accessing its objects. cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { cursor.getLong(0) } etc

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to be the one producing that particular exception: you never move the cursor to index 0 in the first place.

Comment: @AmodGokhale What do you mean by run? Sorry im kind of new to this

Comment: if you have standalone database Train_list.db and if you run select * from command there.. does it return any records? If not then your select query is incorrect

Comment: as mentioned by @laalto above. get cursor to move to first position and then only access its objects

Comment: I moved the Cursor To the first position by using 'header.movetofirst()' and it still gives me the same error

Comment: **`moveToFirst`** (like all Cursor move???? methods) will be false if the move cannot be made (for moveToFirst then if there is no first row i.e. an empty cursor). You need to check the result. e.g. `if (header.moveToFirst()) { do your stuff here } else { handle no data in the cursor here }`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find this, you need to add

```
?
```

in you rawQuery statement

```
header = db1.rawQuery("Select * From Train_list Where Train_no= ?'"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'", null)
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157827/why-am-i-getting-a-column-doesnt-exist-error-with-the-name-of-the-table/47157854#47157854)

Comment: @ArunMani, 
rawQuery("SELECT Train_name FROM Train_list WHERE Train_no = ?", new String[] {message.substring(0,(message.length()-3)});